# How to send div text to clipboard when button is clicked using zeroclipboard?

Tags: javascript, zeroclipboard

Im trying to use zeroclipboard to copy text of 3 divs to the clipboard

What I want is to send the content of `Tittle, Version, and Descript` to the clipboard when the copy button got clicked so that user will be able to use it. It is basically a book reference.

The text on my div is unselectable because it has swipe actions that changes the value of the Title Version and Descript to the next available data on my database.

This is why I need the copy button that will send the current data of the divs to the clipboard.

So far this is what I have. I'm barely trying to send the text of the descript but nothing happens.

My ZeroClipboard seems properly loaded as far as i can tell because the console is showing movie loaded. But when I click the button, nothing happens.

I will appreciate anyone's help.

Thanks

Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/2.2.0/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="MyContent">
            <div id="title">The Book Title</div>
            <div id="version">The Book Version</div>
            <div id="descript">This is the short description of the book</div>
            <button class="descript" accesskey="C">Copy</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var client = new ZeroClipboard( $('#descript') );

  client.on( 'ready', function(event) {
    console.log( 'movie is loaded' );

    client.on( 'copy', function(event) {
      event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', event.target.innerHTML);
    } );

    client.on( 'aftercopy', function(event) {
      console.log('Copied text to clipboard: ' + event.data['text/plain']);
    } );
  } );

  client.on( 'error', function(event) {
    console.log( 'ZeroClipboard error of type "' + event.name + '": ' + event.message );
    ZeroClipboard.destroy();
  } );
</script>
```

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/c09x4jym/3/ thanks

Comment: I ended up using work around method described here https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2014/12/02/definitive-guide-copying-pasting-javascript/ I use hidden text area that automatically updates its value and always selected. Users are adviced to just press CTRL + C to copy the value of the hidden text area.